# Insert missing dates in dataframe for each product and shop

Tags: r

Here's my datafile.

```
Location.Name   Item.Description    Sort.In.Date    OrderedQty
HC Overijse     Pro B 731           7/1/2015        2
HC Overijse     Pro B 731           8/3/2015        2
HC Overijse     Pro B 931           8/27/2015       1
HC Overijse     Pro B 933           6/24/2015       2
HC Overijse     Pro B 933           7/22/2015       2
HC Overijse     Pro B 933           7/29/2015       1
HC Overijse     Pro R 731           6/16/2015       2
HC Overijse     Pro R 731           8/3/2015        2
Hannah Thieuw   Pro B 933           7/14/2015       2
Hannah Thieuw   Pro R 731           8/14/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro B 731           6/12/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro B 931           6/12/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro B 933           6/4/2015        2
HC Asse         Pro R 731           6/8/2015        2
HC Asse         Pro R 731           6/10/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro R 731           6/17/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro R 731           7/9/2015        2
HC Asse         Pro R 731           7/27/2015       2
HC Asse         Pro R 732           6/16/2015       2
```

My question is how do you calculate the average ordered quantity per day/week for the period 6/1/20105->8/31/2015 (without weekends). Per location and per product. So I have to find a way to insert zero's into the dataset to calculate the average. (this will be a small value). I also need the stand dev. I used this code for calculating the average orderdQty per order and the time between 2 orders.

```
fe <- fe[order(fe$Item.Description,fe$Location.Name,fe$Sort.In.Date), ]
sfe<-dlply(fe, .(fe$Item.Description,fe$Location.Name))

fe$DayBetween <- unlist(sapply(seq_along(sfe), function(x)          diff(as.Date(c(NA, as.Date(sfe[[x]][,3] ,  format="%d/%m/%Y") ))) ))


FilteredExport<-fe
remove(fe)

results<-ddply(FilteredExport, .(Location.Code,Location.Name,Item.Description),summarize,
               N=length(Item.Description), AverageQty = mean(OrderedQty),sdAverageQty=sd(OrderedQty) , AvgTimeBetweenOrder = mean(DayBetween,na.rm=TRUE),sdAvgTimeBetweenOrder=sd(DayBetween,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Here is dput of my data:

```
structure(list(Location.Name = c("HC Overijse", "HC Overijse", 
"HC Overijse", "HC Overijse", "HC Overijse", "HC Overijse", "HC Overijse", 
"HC Overijse", "Hannah Thieuw", "Hannah Thieuw", "HC Asse", "HC Asse", 
"HC Asse", "HC Asse", "HC Asse", "HC Asse", "HC Asse", "HC Asse", 
"HC Asse"), Item.Description = c("Pro B 731", "Pro B 731", "Pro B 931", 
"Pro B 933", "Pro B 933", "Pro B 933", "Pro R 731", "Pro R 731", 
"Pro B 933", "Pro R 731", "Pro B 731", "Pro B 931", "Pro B 933", 
"Pro R 731", "Pro R 731", "Pro R 731", "Pro R 731", "Pro R 731", 
"Pro R 732"), Sort.In.Date = structure(c(16617, 16650, 16674, 
16610, 16638, 16645, 16602, 16650, 16630, 16661, 16598, 16598, 
16590, 16594, 16596, 16603, 16625, 16643, 16602), class = "Date"), 
    OrderedQty = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Location.Name", 
"Item.Description", "Sort.In.Date", "OrderedQty"), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why fill with zeros? Just sum the `OrderedQty` and divide by the number of days/weeks of the period.

Comment: Well, how do I calculate the standard variation?

Comment: Ok, i can indeed calculate it all by myself, but is their a way to use a function like mean and sd? Like in the answer of bramtayl

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(date = Sort.In.Date %>% as.Date,
         day_of_week = date %>% format("%w") %>% as.numeric) %>%
  full_join(data_frame(date = as.Date("6/1/2015"):as.Date("8/31/2015") %>% as.Date) ) %>%
  mutate(OrderedQty.expand = OrderedQty %>% mapvalues(NA, 0) )  %>%
  filter(date %>% between(as.Date("6/1/2015"), as.Date("8/31/2015") ) &
         day_of_week %>% between(1, 5) ) %>%
  group_by(Location.Name, Item.Description) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  summarize(OrderedQty.mean = mean(OrderedQty.expand),
            OrderedQty.sd = sd(OrderedQty.expand),
            average_interval = date %>% diff %>% mean)
```

Comment: can you explain what the %>% does? I never saw something like that

Comment: Also iItried to use your code but I can't find the function arrange_by. Which package should I load to use this ?

Comment: `arrange_by` should just be `arrange`. The `%>%` is a "chaining" operator that allows you to run one function after the other without saving to an object in between. The next function just gets the output of the previous function. See the [`dplyr` vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) for more info, particularly the section on chaining.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful. But I am still looking to use the functions mean and sd to calculate the average and std. dev. for all the days where the orderedQty is 0, and thus not included in the dataset